# relationship between grid,store and delbutton

Tags: extjs

I have a simple example:

```
Model1.getBottomToolbar().items.item('Model1Del'). on('click',function() {
rec = Model1.getSelectionModel().getSelected()
Model1.store.remove(rec)
})
```

it's work but it's not readable :). I want to create a DelButton object:

```
DelButtonForGrid = Ext.extend ( Ext.Button, {
   onclick:
    rec = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected()
     grid.store.remove(rec)
   ....
})
```

it's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems proper. use the button as `new DelButtonForGrid ()` . And the record variable isn't proper in `grid.store.remove(recc)`, use "rec" instead of "recc"

Comment: but how to get access to grid or store in DelButtonFOrGrid ?. I don't want to use a global variable.